wp_update_plugins hook is not updating plugins in WP multisite
I have a WP multisite, but currently only one site. I'm using the WP Crontrol to trigger the wp_update_plugins hook on this site in order to be sure it is triggered. But even when doing this the plugins are not updating. Also, if I go to plugins in the admin menu of this site, I can not update the plugins.
However, If I instead go to the admin network view - plugins, here I can update each of the plugins without any problem. But how can I trigger the wp_update_plugins hook in the network manually or automatically? From what i've read, wp-cron.php is only available for each site - there is no wp-cron.php for the network, right?

Despite wp_update_plugins name it does not actually perform any updates, it only checks for available updates.
A list of all plugins installed is sent to WP, along with the site locale. Checks against the WordPress server at api.wordpress.org. Will only check if WordPress isn’t installing.

WordPress has the feature to Enable Auto-Updates for Each Plugin:
You can check this by going to 'Plugins' and here you will find a list of installed plugins. Under the "Auto-update" column, we can enable auto-updates for each plugin individually by clicking the link that says Enable Auto-updates. With the help of this feature WordPress allow us to update these plugins automatically when new versions are released.

If you want to enable Auto update for all WordPress plugin, you can do that by adding given code to functions.php file of the theme.
add_filter('auto_update_plugin', '__return_true');

@NarendraSishodiya Thank you. I have enabled auto-update for all my plugins, but they do not update automatically. I have a cron job curl https://www.example.com/wp-cron.php that runs every 10 minutes. According to documentation plugins should update 2 times every day, but they don't. I guess this is because I have a multisite installation? What hook is triggering update of plugins?
